# how to allow user to enter only specific characters of password and validate it in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

lets say the user's password is gjdA76*?sr. The login page should just show 3 different password box - one for 2nd character, one for 4th character and one for 8th character. This means that the user will enter the following input on the screen : 
j in 1st box
A in second box
? in third box
Using this much input only the password should be validated in HTML. How to do this?

PS: I need the code to do this. Please dont give suggestions on security.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: Consider security and have the password validation at the server side not in the HTML with JS.

Comment: This is high security vulnerable.
if password is abcdefgh and you say that user has to type b, d and h only to get logged in

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your answer correct then the following may be a solution for you.

```
var password = "gjdA76*?sr";
function isEqual(position) {
    return (password.charAt(position - 1) === document.getElementById('char' + position).value);
}
$('#verify').click(function() {
    var equal = isEqual(2) && isEqual(4) && isEqual(8);
  alert(equal);
});
```

---

```
<input id="char2" type="password" maxlength="1">
<input id="char4" type="password" maxlength="1">
<input id="char8" type="password" maxlength="1">
<button id="verify">Verify</button>
```

See also the example at https://jsfiddle.net/4usxrfrr/.

As already mentioned, you should considered your security strategy here.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. But, the password needs to be checked from the database. It can be any user's password . So how to do that?

Comment: If you _really want_ the password be present on the client side, you may use an hidden input field. See https://jsfiddle.net/4usxrfrr/1/ for an example. What kind of server side technologies are you using? There may be a superiorly solution...

Comment: There will be an HTML form for login page to take userame and password input (which will be 3 different characters as stated). Now this password input has to be checked from the database if its correct. I need a code to check if the password is correct and if false login fail message will appear else it will redirect to the next page.

Comment: Ok, so far I've understood. But what technologies can you use on the server side? Do you use PHP or .NET, for example? What kind of database is available and how do you generate the HTML pages? Are these only static or can you generate content dynmically?

Comment: okay i wrote that code. Now the  password characters has to be sent to database. how to do it?

Comment: I can’t answer your question if I don’t know which kind of technologies you are using at the server side. _Send data to database_ is too general. AJAX is a common way to send and retrieve data. But there must be some kind of technology, which proceed these data. Or do you use all that stuff locally?